# How to Generate a Random Code From a Text File in Python

Tags: python

I have written a few lines which are able to recall and print one symbol at a time from a text file (captcha.txt) consisting of 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789' << this ASCII

```
   import random
   import os
    
thisfolder = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
captchatxt = os.path.join(thisfolder, 'captcha.txt')

with open(captchatxt) as text_file:
    captcha = text_file.read()
    random_word = random.choice(captcha)
    print (random_word)
```

However this code only recalls ONE at a time. I can't get my head around to finding a way to recall 6 at a time e.g. J64f7E. The only way I assume how is by creating a loop that compiles these random letters/digits and prints them at the end of the loop - which I still cannot achieve, any solution would be highly beneficial. Thanks.

EDIT:

```
import random 
import os
    
thisfolder = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
captchatxt = os.path.join(thisfolder, 'captcha.txt')

with open(captchatxt) as text_file:
    captcha = text_file.read()
    print (''.join(random.choices(captcha, k=6)))
```

This version is the working one. Thanks everyone. :)

Comment: `random.choices(captcha, k=6)` (Note `choices` rather than `choice`.)

Comment: Or to join them up into a string, `''.join(.....)` where `.....` is what I wrote above.

Comment: @alaniwi Yeah, practically it would be easier to have all possible letters/digits already within the code, however I specifically need to read and recall the text file contents. Thanks.

Comment: Hard-coded one was just an example - already changed above to use your variable.

Comment: Yeah, I'm attemting to incorporate it now, thanks alls good so far.

Comment: By the way, `choices` will not do exactly the same as a simple loop here, because the same character will not be repeated. Would you prefer if you can have the same character more than once, or only once?

Comment: Correction, `choices` will let you repeat letters. I am thinking of `random.sample(captcha, 6)` which would be the way to *not* repeat letters. Okay, you have both options now.

Comment: @alaniwi Specifically, where do I make the modification for .join and remove the concatenated letters that are outputted e.g.  '['p', 'Q', 'H', 'I', 'o', 'O']'

Comment: As I said above, `''.join(....)` will join the strings in the list into a single string (e.g. `pQHIoO`) but I don't understand what you mean here by "remove".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random
print(''.join(random.choices(open('captcha.txt').read().strip(), k=6)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You try choices()

```
random_word = random.choices(captcha, weights=None, cum_weights=None, k=6)
```